# The Relationship between Separable Functors and Faithful Functors

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Consider the adjunction $\mathcal{C} \mathrel{\substack{\mathcal{F}\\\rightleftarrows\\ \mathcal{G}}} \mathcal{D}
$ together with unit $\eta: I_{\!_{\mathcal{C}}} \rightarrow \mathcal{G} \mathcal{F} $ and counit $\varepsilon:\mathcal{F} \mathcal{G} \rightarrow I_{\!_{\mathcal{D}}}$. Then by theorem in Mac Lane's book, $\mathcal{G}$ is faithful if and only if the counit $\varepsilon_{\!_D}$ is epic for $D \in \mathcal{D}$. Rafael's theorem (this is one part of the theorem, and the other is just its dual) for separable functors states that $\mathcal{G}$ is separable if and only if the counit $\varepsilon$ cosplits. From the definition of separability, we have: if $\mathcal{G}$ is separable, then $\mathcal{G}$ is faithful. I also know that a functor is fully separable iff it is fully faithful, but do we have the following: If $\mathcal{G}$ is faithful, then it is separable? If not, can we get a counter example?

Thanks,

Comment: That isn't the statement of Rafael's theorem on the nLab: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separable+functor

Comment: You are right! I have corrected the statement. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Qiaochu's comment: The theorem written on the nLab states that $\mathcal G$ is separable iff the counit $\epsilon$ has a retraction, i.e. a left inverse. This implies that $\epsilon$ is a *monomorphism*, but is not equivalent to it.

In case that was your confusion: Qiaochu himself has written a nice post on his blog that I read a few weekss ago explaining the difference between epic and having a right inverse. https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/split-epimorphisms-and-split-monomorphisms/

Comment: Thanks George! 

Based on Rafael's paper (Separable functors revisited), the statement should be  $\mathcal G$ is separable iff the counit $\epsilon$ has a coretraction, i.e. a right inverse. This implies that $\epsilon$ is an *epimorphism*. So I think the statement in nLab is not correct. 
Best,

http://www.tandfonline.com.proxy.lib.uiowa.edu/doi/pdf/10.1080/00927879008823975

Comment: I'm unfortunately not anywhere near my university and won't be during the following weeks, so I can't look at that paper. I do however think, you are right: Both the first paper cited on the nLab article http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869389900537 as well as http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.1332 define a functor $F: \mathcal C \rightarrow \mathcal D$ to be separable iff the induced binatural transformation $\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(-,-) \rightarrow \text{hom}_\mathcal{D}(F-,F-)$ has a *left inverse*, unlike stated in the nLab.

Comment: This implies directly that $F$ is faithful, is however not equivalent to it. (The condition of having a retraction is in general stronger than being a monomorphism, which goes back to the blogpost I link).